4K desktop (KDE Plasma) and scaling with RDP sessions blown out of proportion
Hopefully this is a simple fix.  I have Debian Bookworm with KDE Plasma on a 4K monitor.  So just like with Win10 I must use scaling or else everything is just tiny.
However, in KDE/Plasma, with that scaling active, also my RDP sessions are scaled up.  Where that is not desirable at all.  Win10 was smart enough to know not to scale up RDP sessions so as to keep the desired RDP screen resolution.
Im using Remmina but not stuck on them.
Is there a way to obtain this also with KDE on a 4K?
